# Writing Test Apex Class for Custom Controller on VFP

Tags: apex

I've looked at multiple questions & answers on here, as well as just googling! I'm new to this and am sure I'm not approaching this correctly.

I'm attempting to create a test class for my Custom Controller for a VFP I have. The VFP is to display an uploaded document on a Document Checklist Item record, and references two data points from the Custom Controller (version Id and content document Id).

In my test, I create a Document Checklist Item, Content Version, and the Content Document Link. I then grab the VFP and the Controller. No matter what I attempt to input, I cannot get the correct method to pull. Maybe my Controller is not optimally set up? It does do the job I need it to!

What am I not referencing or potentially not setting up correctly? This line in the Test Class is giving me a method error:
**<PreviewDocumentPageLatestVersion_Test> Line 42 : Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void getDocumentChecklistItemList() from the type PreviewDocumentPageLatestVersion**

Controller:

```java
public with sharing class PreviewDocumentPageLatestVersion {
    public String ContentDocumentId {get;set;}
    public String ContentVersionRecordId {get;set;}
    public String ContentDocumentRecord {get; set;}
    public String ContentVersionRecord {get; set;}
        
    public List<DocumentChecklistItem> DocumentChecklistItemList {get; set;}
    public List<ContentDocument> ContentDocumentList {get; set;}
    public List<ContentVersion> ContentVersionList {get; set;}
        
    public PreviewDocumentPageLatestVersion() {
        DocumentChecklistItemList = [SELECT Id, Name, Attached_Document_Id_del__c from DocumentChecklistItem where Id = :ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id')];
        {
            for(DocumentChecklistItem dci : DocumentChecklistItemList){
                ContentDocumentRecord = String.valueOf(dci.Attached_Document_Id_del__c).substring(0, 18);
            }
            
            ContentDocumentList = [SELECT Id, LatestPublishedVersionId from ContentDocument where Id = :ContentDocumentRecord];
            {
                for(ContentDocument cd : ContentDocumentList){
                    ContentVersionRecord = String.valueOf(cd.LatestPublishedVersionId).substring(0, 18);
                }
                    
                ContentVersionList = [SELECT Id FROM ContentVersion WHERE IsLatest = TRUE AND ContentDocumentId = :ContentDocumentRecord LIMIT 1];
                {
                    for(ContentVersion cv : ContentVersionList){
                        ContentVersionRecordId = String.valueOf(cv.Id).substring(0, 18);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Test Class:

```java
@isTest
private class PreviewDocumentPageLatestVersion_Test {
    @isTest
    static void testSysAdmin() {
        //start test
        Test.startTest();
        //create Admin user
        User admin = getSysAdmin();
        insert admin;               
                
        //create Document Checklist Item  record
        DocumentChecklistItem dci = new DocumentChecklistItem (Name = 'Test Apex', ParentRecordId = '5007c00000FNY1HAAX');
        insert dci;
                
        //create Content Version/Document record
        ContentVersion contentVersion = new ContentVersion(
            Title          = 'a picture',
            PathOnClient   = 'Pic.jpg',
            VersionData    = Blob.valueOf('Test Content'),
            IsMajorVersion = true
        );
        insert contentVersion;
        
        List<ContentDocument> documents = [SELECT Id, Title, LatestPublishedVersionId FROM ContentDocument];
                
        //create ContentDocumentLink  record
        ContentDocumentLink cdl = new ContentDocumentLink();
        cdl.LinkedEntityId = dci.Id;
        cdl.ContentDocumentId = documents[0].Id;
        cdl.ShareType = 'V';
        cdl.Visibility = 'AllUsers';
        insert cdl;
        
        //Grab Visualforce Page
        PageReference pageRef = Page.PreviewDocumentPage;
        Test.setCurrentPage(pageRef);
        ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('id', dci.id);
                
        //test Visualforce Page Custom Controller
        ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('id', String.valueOf(dci.Id));
        Test.setCurrentPage(pageRef);
        PreviewDocumentPageLatestVersion  testController = new PreviewDocumentPageLatestVersion();
        testController.getDocumentChecklistItemList();
                
        //stop test
        Test.stopTest();
    }
            
    //static data for creating user
    static User getSysAdmin() {
        Id pId = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name = 'System Administrator' LIMIT 1].Id;
        return getUserWithProfile(pId);
    }

    static User getUserWithProfile(Id profileId) {
        return new User(
            ProfileId = profileId,
            Alias = 'test', 
            Email = 'test@test.com', 
            EmailEncodingKey = 'UTF-8', 
            LastName = 'Testing', 
            LanguageLocaleKey = 'en_US', 
            LocaleSidKey = 'en_US', 
            TimeZoneSidKey = 'America/New_York', 
            UserName = 'fmz-test@test.com'
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SFSE!. Please see [ask] on getting the most from the community. Please use [edit] and identify which lines are not working?  Note you shouldn't have  to do the substrings

Comment: @cropredy Thank you! I'm new to posting on here, so every bit of help is much appreciated!

I've added the portion after the question, but I couldn't highlight the section specifically :
"What am I not referencing or potentially not setting up correctly? This line in the Test Class is giving me a method error: testController.getDocumentChecklistItemList();"

Is this better?

Comment: Please also include the error message and stack trace (the `<class name here>: line x, column y` parts) as well. Also, be sure to copy/paste it _verbatim_ (if you paraphrase, it's very likely you'll leave out subtle, important information).

Comment: @DerekF added! :)  This line in the Test Class is giving me a method error: <PreviewDocumentPageLatestVersion_Test> Line 42 : Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void getDocumentChecklistItemList() from the type PreviewDocumentPageLatestVersion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `...method does not exist...` error makes sense given the code you've provided so far and the line that you've indicated the problem is on.

Your controller class does not have a `getDocumentChecklistItemList()` method.

What you have instead is an instance *property* (a variable with an in-line getter/setter).

You access properties the same way you do with variables. So drop the "get" and the parenthesis at the end, and that particular error will disappear.

```java
// other code omitted

//test Visualforce Page Custom Controller
ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('id', String.valueOf(dci.Id));
Test.setCurrentPage(pageRef);
PreviewDocumentPageLatestVersion  testController = new PreviewDocumentPageLatestVersion();

// remove the "get" and "()"
// also, store the result in a variable (which I assume you'll later use for making
//   assertions)
List<DocumentChecklistItem> results = testController.documentChecklistItemList;

//stop test
Test.stopTest();
```

A few last things...

- Assertions are what make unit tests useful (i.e. they're what help demonstrate that your code is working as intended), so don't forget to make some assertions. Assert things like "I get exactly 1 result back", "The result is related to the Id I passed into my controller", "If a record doesn't have any content, return an empty list and don't run into an exception", etc...
- Each individual test method should try to test only a single scenario. So your test class should probably have multiple test methods.

Comment: thank you!!!  This worked! I added this assertion on blind assumption after updating what I had to what you provided (I updated 'results' to 'dcliresults'), and the test passed - is it actually doing anything? System.assertEquals(1, dcliresults.size());

Comment: @lexiesteven - you should be asserting that all the properties you are exposing to the VFP are set properly